# Spring Batch Reader Writer transfer of data not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have created a Generic Spring Batch job for Processing of Data and storing into a CSV. I need some data from the Reader passed into the writer which I am trying to do using JobExecution. However suprisingly, the code seems to call the getWriter() first than the getReader() function.
My config is given below. Could someone explain why it is happening and if there is any alternative way to pass data from reader to writer.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReader<Map<String, Object>> getDataReader() throws Exception {
    return springBatchReader.getReader();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWriter<Map<String, Object>> getDataWriter() throws Exception {
    return (FlatFileItemWriter<Map<String, Object>>) springBatchWriter.getWriter();
}

@Bean
public Job SpringBatchJob(Step generateReport) throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("SpringBatchJob" + System.currentTimeMillis())
            .preventRestart()
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(generateReport)
            .end()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step generateReport() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("generateReport").<Map<String, Object>, Map<String, Object>>chunk(batchSize)
            .reader(getDataReader()).writer(getDataWriter()).build();
}
```

The Data I want to pass from Reader to Writer is the column names for the CSV. **Since my Reader runs variable SQL queries(passing the SQL query to be run as a command line argument) and hence the result-set/columns are not static and vary based on the given query. To provide the writer with the column names to be written for that particular execution in the setHeaderCallback was the rationale behind sending data from Reader to Writer.**

The Reader simple runs the given query and puts the data into Map<String, Object> rather than any POJO due to the variable nature of the data. Here the key of the Map represent the column name while the corresponding object holds the values for that column. So essentially I want the writer setHeaderCallback to be able to access Keys of the passed Map or pass the keys from the Reader to the Writer somehow.

The Writer Code is as follows:

```
public FlatFileItemWriter<Map<String, Object>> getWriter() throws Exception {
        String reportName = getReportName();
        saveToContext(reportName, reportPath);

        FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource(String.join(File.separator, reportPath, getReportName()));

        FlatFileItemWriter<Map<String, Object>> flatFileItemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        flatFileItemWriter.setResource(resource);
//NEED HELP HERE..HOW TO SET THE HEADER TO BE THE KEYS OF THE MAP
//flatFileItemWriter.setHeaderCallback();
        flatFileItemWriter.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<Map<String, Object>>() {

            {
                setDelimiter(delimiter);
                setFieldExtractor(
                        new PassThroughFieldExtractor<>()
                );
            }
        });
        flatFileItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return flatFileItemWriter;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The execution order of those methods does not matter. You should not be looking for a way to pass data from the reader to the writer using the execution context, the Chunk-oriented Tasklet implementation provided by Spring Batch will do that for you.

The execution context could be used to pass data from one step to another, but not from the reader to the writer within the same step.

EDIT: update answer based on comments:

Your issue is that you are calling `saveToContext(reportName, reportPath);` in the getWriter method. This method is called at configuration time and not at runtime.

What you really need is provide the column names either via job parameters or put them in the execution context with a step, then use a step-scoped Header callback that is configured with those headers.

You can find an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56719077/5019386. This example is for the lineMapper but you can do the same for the headerCallback. If you don't want to use the job parameters approach, you can create a tasklet step that determines column names and puts them in the execution context, then configure the step-scoped header callback with those names from the execution context, something like:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileHeaderCallback headerCallback(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['columnNames']}") String columnNames) {
    return new FlatFileHeaderCallback() {
        @Override
        public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
            // use columnNames here
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud. However could you guide a bit about how Chunk-Oriented Tasklet can be used for the purpose(updating the details of what I was trying to do in the question.) The resources I found online seemed a bit confusing for the task at hand.

Thanks !

Comment: You are already using a chunk-oriented tasklet. So it will handle passing items from reader to writer. You can check the [implementation if you want](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/step/item/ChunkOrientedTasklet.java), but in essence, items are handed through a variable: `Chunk inputs = chunkProvider.provide(); chunkProcessor.process(inputs);`

Comment: Updated the use case details the question Mahmoud. Request you to kindly suggest if any alternate approaches are available, without the need to pass the data explicitly. Rather new to Spring-batch!

Comment: Thanks for the update. The initial question was misleading, and was missing the key detail about your requirement of dynamically getting the column names for the header callback. You could have updated this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67477713/spring-batch-itemwriter-with-dynamic-header instead of creating a new one where I asked you where those column names come from.

Comment: Anyway, no problem. I updated the answer with more details and an example.