# Spring Batch FlatFileItemReader Handle Additional Fields Added to CSV

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

So I've got a csv file that's being ingested on a scheduled basis. The csv file has a set of columns with their names specified in the header row, the catch is, new columns are constantly being added to this csv. Currently, when a new field is added, the ingest flow breaks and I get a FlatFileParseException. I have to go in and update the code with the new column names in order to have it work again.

What I'm looking to accomplish, is instead, when new columns are added, have the code correctly pick out the columns it needs, and not throw an exception.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
FlatFileItemReader<Foo> fooReader(
...
) {

final DelimitedLineTokenizer fooLineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer(",") {{
  final String[] fooColumnNames = { "foo", "bar" };
  setNames(fooColumnNames);

  // setStrict(false);
  
}};

return new FlatFileItemReader<>() {{
  setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<>() {{
    setLineTokenizer(fooLineTokenizer);
    setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>() {{
      setTargetType(Foo.class);
    }});
  }});

  ...

}};
}
```

I've tried using setStrict(false) in the lineTokenizer, and this gets rid of the exception, however the problem then becomes fields being set to the wrong values from the new columns that were added, as opposed to the original columns the data was being pulled from.

Any ideas on how to add a bit more fault-tolerance to this flow, so I don't have to constantly update the `fooColumnNames` whenever columns are added to the csv?

I tried modifying the code using the setStrict(false) parameter and toying with custom implementations of lineTokenizer, but still struggling to get fault-tolerance when new columns are added to the csv

Comment: if you know that a change has been introduced to the header, you can pass the updated column names as job parameters, see example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710477/how-could-i-assign-dynamic-properties-to-a-spring-batch-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about fault tolerance, but it could possible to retrieve columns dynamically

Add a listener to your step to retrieve columns in beforeStep and pass it to your stepExecutionContext

```java
public class ColumnRetrieverListener implements StepExecutionListener {

    private Resource resource;

    //Getter and setter

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        String[] columns = getColumns();
        stepExecution.getExecutionContext().put("columns", columns);
    }

    private String[] getColumns() {
        //Parse first line of resource to get columns
    }
}
```

Use the data passed to execution context to set lineTokenizer

```java
final DelimitedLineTokenizer fooLineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer(",") {{
            final String[] fooColumnNames = (String[]) stepExecution.getExecutionContext().get("columns");
            setNames(fooColumnNames);

        }};
```

Comment: Ended up doing something similar to this, only caveat is it will additionally require csvTokenizer.setIncludedFields(...) if additional unrecognized fields are being added to the csv, which is the case for me.